# Python: Fitting circles in between two curves in log scale, in order to connect the circle origins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two curves plotted in log y-scale (red & blue).

How do I fit in imaginary circles in between the curves, so that I can connect the origins of the circles to form another curve?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

xmin, xmax = 2000, 7000
ymin, ymax = 10, 50000

#arrays
x_grid = np.array([2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000])
y_blue_grid = np.array([15, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
y_red_grid = np.array([20, 400, 10000, 500000, 500000, 500000])

# create interpolating curves in logspace
tck_red = interpolate.splrep(x_grid, np.log(y_red_grid), s=0)
tck_blue = interpolate.splrep(x_grid, np.log(y_blue_grid), s=0)
tck_green = interpolate.splrep(x_grid, np.log(y_green_grid), s=0)
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax)
yr = np.exp(interpolate.splev(x, tck_red, der=0))
yb = np.exp(interpolate.splev(x, tck_blue, der=0))

#plot the curves
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.set_xlim(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.plot(x, yr, color='red')
plt.plot(x, yb, color='blue')
```

The figure below shows the rough sketch of the green curve formed by connecting the origins of the imaginary circles.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Is the imaginary circles method important?  Or are you looking for anything that can help you find a curve centered between two other curves?

Comment: bisector for general angles are not that easy...

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60902/formulas-for-equidistant-curves

Comment: @Owen No, any other methods would suffice. Other averaging methods that I tried, skews the center curve since it is in logspace.